# My function to find the x coordinate of the mouse doesn't work

Tags: javascript, dom-events, document-body

I set `document.body.onmousemove` to the following function so that the console will log the X coordinate of the mouse on the page whenever the mouse is moved inside the body.

```
document.body.onmousemove = "function mouseX(e){console.log(e.clientX);}(event)";
```

This doesn't work.  It produces no errors, but nothing happens.  When I check the value of `document.body.onmousemove` I get null.

Note that I want to have this script injected through the JavaScript console, so I don't want html code and I would prefer not to use any JavaScript libraries either.

Comment: Try it simply with an anonymous function: `document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {console.log(e.clientX);}` and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `document.body.onmousemove = function mouseX(e){console.log(e.clientX);}`

You were assigning a string to `document.body.onmousemove` when you should have been assigning a function that you would like to fire when the mouse actually moves.